# What does non degeneracy mean for a preference?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, preferences, decision-theory

I saw a non-degeneracy assumption in Gilboa and Schmeidler's paper (maxmin expected utility with non-unique prior).

The statement is "Not for all $f$ and $g$ in $L$, $f \geq g$".

So can you explain the intuition for this assumption and give some example so that I can understand the "non-degeneracy" property better?

Comment: My first guess would be something related to a [degenerate probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution). But please provide a bit more details: a link to the paper or the full statement of the assumption.

Comment: Hi, here is a link:
 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4902609_Maxmin_Expected_Utility_With_Non-Unique_Prior. The non-degeneracy assumption is on page 144 of the original paper, under the name of A.6.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to understand non-degeneracy if we look at the contrapositive of the statement: 
**There exist (horse lotteries) $f,g\in L$ such that $f>g$.**
In other words, $\geq$ is not a preference relation that treats all horse lotteries in $L$ equally; it strictly prefers some $f$ to some $g$. Unfortunately I can't produce examples to help elucidate this, as I'm not that familiar with this field. Maybe looking up Anscombe-Aumann's definition of subjective probability will help.

Answer (score 1):

It means what Herr K. has guessed: there are acts $f$ and $g$ that the decision maker does not deem equivalent from the preference standpoint. In other words, the DM expresses a strong preference in at least one comparison he makes. a preference that does **not** satisfy it is a AA subjective expected utility with a constant index $u$ (i.e. such that the representation is $\int u dp$ for an arbitrary belief $p$). On the other hand if at least for one comparison the DM says $f$ is strictly better than $g$ then you satisfy it.

Comment: I might add: the reason for this assumption is so that $u(x) = c$ for some constant $c$ does not rationalize the preference. This state of affairs is both boring and destroys any uniqueness results (since beliefs no longer play any role they can be arbitrary).